# Calculate message digest for TSA for CMS_sign prior to CMS_final

Tags: security, openssl, signing, pki, pkcs#7

I have code to create CMS signature. It worked well now I need to add trusted timestamping.

```
BIO *data_output = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
const EVP_MD *sign_md = EVP_get_digestbyname(digest_name);

cms = CMS_sign(NULL, NULL, NULL, bio_in, flags);
BOOST_ASSERT(cms);

for (size_t i = 0; i < m_signers.size(); i++) {
    int tflags = flags;

    SignerInfo si = m_signers[i];

    CMS_SignerInfo *signer_info = CMS_add1_signer(cms,
        si.m_x509, si.m_privateKey, sign_md, tflags);
    BOOST_ASSERT(signer_info != NULL);

    for (int c = 0; c < sk_X509_num(si.m_ca); c++) {
        X509* cert = sk_X509_value(si.m_ca, c);
        BOOST_ASSERT(CMS_add0_cert(cms, cert) != 0);
    }
}

BOOST_ASSERT(CMS_final(cms, bio_in, NULL, flags) != 0);
BOOST_ASSERT(i2d_CMS_bio_stream(data_output, cms, bio_in, flags) != 0);
```

In order to talk to TSA, I need the digest value but there is no way to get the digest value until CMS_final is called. I could not locate the answer anywhere.

Comment: Email me offlist at noloader, gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

id-aa-timeStampToken is an unsigned attribute. If your implementation has no hooks to modify the message afterwards you can do it in two passes. Do call final, get the hash and send it to the TSA. Then build a second identical CMS and add an unsigned id-aa-timeStampToken attibute (OID 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.14). Paste the timestampToken in there and call final.

Be aware that using a timestamp usually requires a SIGNED attribute signing-time Pkcs9SigningTime (OID 1.2.840.113549.1.9.5) so save the time used on the first pass to get two identical CMS messages.

It is a bit cheap but it does the job. If you neeed to ask for a pin on a Smart card it will ask two times.